# Yii site served by nginx or apache only serves main page

Tags: php, yii, nginx

**EDIT ONE:** I've also tested this on Windows 7 with apache, and there the exact same thing happens. This means that the problem is primarily the routing of all pages to the home page.

**EDIT TWO:** As per a suggestion in the #yii IRC channel, I replaced the contents of the .htaccess file with a much-simplified one from a working project. This hasn't yielded any change in the problem, however.

**EDIT THREE: I've got this working just fine now with some changes to my code. Answer below**

I've been trying to import a site written with the Yii Framework that I've imported to my workstation. I'm encountering a problem where trying to load any page does nothing but direct to the main page. This means all requests are essentially routed exactly as if I loaded the root request. No errors pop up in the access log or error log; the requests look like the following in nginx's access log, where 'example' is either 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', or the server's IP address:

```
Accessing root ( http://example/ ): 
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2013:13:05:28 -0700] 
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8436 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0"

Accessing login ( http://example/site/login ):
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2013:13:07:01 -0700] 
"GET /site/login HTTP/1.1" 200 8427 "http://example/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0"

Accessing the same controller by http://example/index.php?r=site/login:
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2013:14:40:45 -0700] 
"GET /index.php?r=site/login HTTP/1.1" 200 8419 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0"
```

Considering I've got 2 other Yii projects set up which work fine, which are using a server configuration similar to which I'll also paste below, I'm thinking that it may be something in the workings of the application itself that I'm not keen to yet. If anyone has any suggestions for anything else I could share, try out, or compare to in the working projects I've imported from other sites, it'd be greatly appreciated :)

**edit: switched in config closer to what I had actually been using. This is probably irrelevant considering the project has the same problem while running in Apache on Windows.**

```
server {
    server_name  localhost;
    listen 80;
    keepalive_timeout 70;

    root /usr/www/[project name omitted]/public_html;

    client_max_body_size 4M;
    client_body_buffer_size 4M;
    client_header_buffer_size 4M;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        autoindex on;
    }

    location ^~ /data/ {
        expires 30d;
    }


    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    #Disable logging for favicon
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    #Disable logging for robots.txt
    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ /themes/\w+/views {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Pass all .php files onto a php-fpm/php-fcgi server.
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        try_files $uri =404;
        #fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        #fastcgi_connect_timeout 20;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 20;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600; # For xdebug to work alright
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got everything sorted out after contacting the original developer of this project, who has informed me of a few changes that needed to be made. They are as follows:

- Updating instances of code that looks like this:

  ```
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['allowdownload'] = true;
  session_write_close();
  ```
- With this:

  ```
  $session=new CHttpSession;
  $session->open();
  $session['allowdownload'] = true;
  $session->close();
  ```
- As well as changing the setting in protected/config/main.php for 'showScriptName' in the urlManager array to 'true' rather than 'false'. I hope that this helps someone else out at some point!

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this line from your `location /` configuration:

```
index index.html $yii_bootstrap;
```

Basically you tell Nginx that it should always use `$yii_bootstrap` as index file. So the line `try_files` is never used.

Comment: I've actually gone and edited the config file somewhere in between trying something else out than what you saw before (Which is just what I had copied and pasted from what the yii docs themselves have up at https://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/trunk/docs/guide/quickstart.apache-nginx-config.txt ). The edited config file contains somethiung closer to your suggestion, but does absolutely nothing to solve my problem still. I'm going to try this with apache instead - I still doubt this is an nginx problem at this rate, but I may be wrong. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that I can see. Generally for Yii apps I have my location block setup as follows. Not the "~" and the forward slash before your index.php file. I'd also move your index option *outside* of that location block and into the server root block. So your location block should look as follows

```
 location ~ / { 
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
 }
```

The second thing has to do with your php location block. Unless you're running multiple php files, you only need to specify access to index.php rather than allow access to *any* web facing php file.

```
location ~ index.php$ {
```

This location block should work for you though:

```
location ~ index.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /path/to/yii/app$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors        off;
    fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 60; 
    fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I recognize this facilitates a more proper and secure setup. I probably should have just posted my actual config up in the first place, the one you saw up there was just what the yii docs suggested. However, these aren't the only php files being run on the server, so as far as it goes your suggestion isn't an answer to my problem at all, which still stands with only the main page loading with anything I try doing on the site, meaning none of the other actions return their respective views.